# How Does Xcode Use The Macbook Pro Touchbar?

Tags: xcode, macbookpro-touch-bar

I am looking at getting the 13 inch macbook pro with the touchbar. I am going to be using it for Xcode development. I was wondering how does Xcode use the touchbar. Meaning that what function keys for xcode come up on the touchbar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From this [article](https://adtmag.com/articles/2016/10/28/xcode-8-1.aspx):

> New features in the IDE to support Touch Bar development include:
>
> - Touch Bar displays context-specific buttons when in the Xcode editor,
>     commit sheet, navigator and Interface Builder.
> - Debug button in the
>     Control Strip lets you pause and inspect your app while Xcode is in
>     the background.
> - Interface Builder button updates the frames of
>     selected objects and their children.
> - Classes in Interface Builder make
>     it easy to add Touch Bar features to your Mac apps.
> - Touch Bar
>     simulator works on any Mac so you can see how your app works with the
>     Touch Bar.

Comment: @ConfusedDeer this is heartbreaking! ouch!

Comment: @TonyAdams I guess they heard me, cause it now has step-over, step-into, etc, buttons on the touchscreen.

Comment: @ConfusedDeer I was looking for that feature, I don't see it on Xcode 10, where do you see it?

Comment: I just needed to tap the magic icon? or the spraying can icon to expand the set of buttons.